# cheerio data diffusion confusion

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

Have a list of such a links. Want the value of the data key using cheerio/JQuery selector.
1 link:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn.stuff.stuff2" data-diffusion-decimal="1.9090" >xxx</a>
```

Have tried this:

```
$("a.ui-btn.stuff.stuff2").each(function(i, r) {
            const decimal = $(r).data("diffusionDecimal");
}
```

Get decimal not defined.

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
$("a.ui-btn.stuff.stuff2").each(function(i, a) {
  const decimal = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-diffusion-decimal"))
}
```

I'm not sure about that class, you might need `a[class="ui-btn.stuff.stuff2"]`